# Characteristic Polynomial on 3 by 3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The given matrix is

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
2  &  4 &  3 \\
 -4 & -6 & -3 \\
  3  & 3  & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Any alternative idea than computing
$|A-xI|$?
$$A - xI = \begin{pmatrix}
2-x   &4   &   3 \\
 -4 &  -6-x  & -3 \\
  3  &   3&   1-x
\end{pmatrix}$$
How to find characterstics equation ??

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In artificial exercises such as this one, you can sometimes save yourself having to grind through the generic method by checking some simple linear combinations of rows and columns. In this case, the sum of the first two rows is $(-2,-2,0)$, so one eigenvalue is $-2$, and the sum of all of the rows is $(1,1,1)$, so another eigenvalue is $1$. The eigenvalues of a matrix and its transpose are identical, so you now have two of the eigenvalues of $A$. You can always get the last one “for free” from the trace, which is the sum of the eigenvalues. Here, we get $(2-6+1)-1-(-2)=-2$ for the third eigenvalue. The characteristic polynomial is therefore $(\lambda+2)^2(\lambda-1)$.

You might also notice that if you subtract the second column from the first, you get $(-2,2,0)^T$, and then add the last column to this to get $(1,-1,1)^T$, which gives you the same two eigenvalues as above, but I found it a bit easier to spot the interesting row sums for this matrix.

Incidentally, the characteristic polynomial is usually defined as being *monic* (not that this affects its roots), so you should probably be computing $\det(\lambda I-A)$ instead, which is guaranteed to produce a monic polynomial for both odd- and even-order matrices. $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is monic only for even orders. On the other hand, subtracting $A$has more potential for making a sign error, so watch out for that.

Comment: How did you know from the sum that the eign value is -2 or 1.?

Comment: So we can use this find the sum of the first and second . Then find the sum of all ??

Comment: @AmerYR Summing the first two rows is equivalent to left-multiplying by $(1,1,0)$; summing all of the rows is equivalent to multiplying by $(1,1,1)$. I recommend studying what the product of a matrix and vector works out to be in terms of the rows or columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Find the determinant  $\det |A-xI|=0$ which gives you a cubic of it is called the characteristic equation. So in your case it comes to $$x^3+3x^2-4=0$$ its roots are $-2,-2,1$ whose sum should be equal to the trace of the matrix (sum of the diagonal elements) and their product equals $-\det|A|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make some linear row or column combinations and use multilinearity:
\begin{align}
&\bigl|A - xI\bigr| = \begin{vmatrix}
2-x   &4   &   3 \\
 -4 &  -6-x  & -3 \\
  3  &   3&   1-x
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
2-x   &4   &   3 \\
 -2-x &  -2-x  & 0 \\
  3  &   3&   1-x
\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
&=(-2-x)\begin{vmatrix}
2-x   &4   &   3 \\
 1&  1  & 0 \\
  3  &   3&   1-x
\end{vmatrix}=(-2-x)\begin{vmatrix}
-2-x   &4   &   3 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 1-x
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(2+x)^2\begin{vmatrix}
 1 &4   &   3 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 1-x
\end{vmatrix}=(2+x)^2\cdot 1\bigl(1\cdot(1-x)-0\cdot3\bigr)=(2+x)^2(1-x).
\end{align}